# text over image in a list item menu

Tags: css

I am having a menu before each menu, and I am having an image before each li to illustrated the menu.

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/dtjmsy/7UHxa/2/

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">
        <img width="40" height="14" src="http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/902607libkgd.png" alt="li_bkgd">Example menu 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My question is how would I do to position the text over the top of the image ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `image` as the *Background-Image* of the list elements.

As per your comments I got your requirement. So here is the solution and its explanation.

1- You need to show the image beneath the text. So there should be some space at the bottom of `li` element. For that we have to use the padding bottom.

2- As you also need to use the background image so that image but the position of background image is not by default set as you want. So you also need to play with it.

Here is your css

```
#menu li
{
    background :url('http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/902607libkgd.png') no-repeat;
    background-position:0px 10px;  // 0px from the left and 10px from the top
    padding:0px 0px 10px 10px;     // 10px padding from the left and bottom to shift the text according to image position
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7UHxa/7/)

Comment: Hi, I tried it too, same thing, how would I position exactly the beginning of the text over the top of the image

Comment: Hi, Sachin, I would like the text just above the eclipse so I can see the whole picture, thanks.

Comment: Hi Sachin, something like that http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/659256eclipsetext.jpg

Comment: Hi Sachin, that' s exactly what I want, thanks a lot, I am trying to understand your css, the code background-position:0px 10px; is to move the background down 10px right ?, but I don' t understand very much the padding:0px 0px 10px 10px;

Comment: Thanks Sachin and all of you. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just change you style as below

```
#menu {
    list-style-type:none;
}
#menu li {
    background :url('http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/902607libkgd.png') no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom left;
    height:30px;
    padding-left:15px;
}
```

Hope this should work..

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Example menu 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And CSS example:

```
#menu li
{
    background :url('example.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: left 1px top -1px;
}
```

Also you can use different background for each item:

```
#menu li:first-child
{
    background :url('example.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: left 1px top -1px;
}
```

Also `:last-child` and `nth-child(2)` selects every `<li>` element that is the second child of its parent